# PANDAS pd.read_hdf works with some, but not all tables in my HDF5 file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py, nastran

I am using Pandas in Python 3.7 in order to read data from a HDF5 file. The HDF5 file contains tables of results from MSC Nastran.

The HDF5 file is named 'ave_01.h5'

The HDF5 table of displacements looks like this:

[image]

Using the following works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.read_hdf('./ave_01.h5', 'NASTRAN/RESULT/NODAL/DISPLACEMENT')
```

However, I have another table for stress results, which looks like this:

[image]

So I would expect the following code to work, but it does not:

```
pd.read_hdf('./ave_01.h5', '/NASTRAN/RESULT/ELEMENTAL/STRESS/QUAD_CN')
```

I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

I have noticed that this second table contains lists in some columns, whereas the first table does not. These lists also contain 5 elements. Perhaps this is causing the error, but I don't know if this is true, nor how to correct for this.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

For reference, these results are of a simple test model, as can be seen below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the issue is associated with the list of 5 elements.

I was able to replicate the issue on my end. In my case, the list has 9 elements, but the read_hdf function expects only one value per table cell.

Below is my Python code with Pandas. Unfortunately, I was not able to work around the issue.

I was able to successfully move forward by using the h5py library instead. Further down is my Python code with the h5py library.

**Pandas**

Working example

```
import pandas as pd

test_output = pd.read_hdf('./nug_46.h5', '/NASTRAN/RESULT/NODAL/DISPLACEMENT')
print(test_output)
# returns
#           ID         X         Y         Z   RX   RY   RZ  DOMAIN_ID
# 0          3 -0.000561 -0.001269  0.001303  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 1          5 -0.001269 -0.000561  0.001303  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 2          6 -0.001342 -0.000668  0.001181  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 3          7 -0.001342 -0.000794  0.001162  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 4          8 -0.001335 -0.000893  0.001120  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# ...      ...       ...       ...       ...  ...  ...  ...        ...
# 4878   20475  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 4879   20478  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 4880  100001  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 4881  100002  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
# 4882  100003  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0          2
```

Non-working example

```
test_output = pd.read_hdf('./nug_46.h5', 'NASTRAN/RESULT/ELEMENTAL/STRESS/HEXA')
print(test_output)
# returns an error
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/home/apricot/PycharmProjects/python_hdf5_reader/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1654, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
#     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
#   File "/home/apricot/PycharmProjects/python_hdf5_reader/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3041, in make_block
#     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
#   File "/home/apricot/PycharmProjects/python_hdf5_reader/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 125, in __init__
#     f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1
```

**H5PY**

Working example

```
import h5py

file = h5py.File('./nug_46.h5', 'r')

# Open the dataset of compound type
dataset = file['/NASTRAN/RESULT/ELEMENTAL/STRESS/HEXA']

# Print the column names
column_names = dataset.dtype.names
print(column_names)
# returns
# ('EID', 'CID', 'CTYPE', 'NODEF', 'GRID', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'TXY', 'TYZ', 'TZX', 'DOMAIN_ID')

# Print the first ten rows of the dataset
# If you want to print the whole dataset, leave out the brackets and
# colon, e.g. enumerate(dataset)
for i, line in enumerate(dataset[0:10]):
    print(line)
# returns
# (447, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,    5,    6,   12,   11, 1716, 1340, 1346, 1345], ..., 2)
# (448, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,    6,    7,   13,   12, 1340, 1341, 1347, 1346], ..., 2)
# (449, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,    7,    8,   14,   13, 1341, 1342, 1348, 1347], ..., 2)
# (450, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,    8,    9,   15,   14, 1342, 1343, 1349, 1348], ..., 2)
# (451, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,    9,   10,   16,   15, 1343, 1344, 1350, 1349], ..., 2)
# (452, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,   11,   12,   18,   17, 1345, 1346, 1352, 1714], ..., 2)
# (453, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,   12,   13,   19,   18, 1346, 1347, 1353, 1352], ..., 2)
# (454, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,   13,   14,   20,   19, 1347, 1348, 1354, 1353], ..., 2)
# (455, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,   14,   15,   21,   20, 1348, 1349, 1355, 1354], ..., 2)
# (456, 0, b'GRID', 8, [   0,   15,   16,   22,   21, 1349, 1350, 1356, 1355], ..., 2)

# Print the 2nd row, 1st column in the dataset
print(dataset[1][column_names[0]])
# returns
# 448

# Print the 2nd row, 5th column, 3rd element of the list in the dataset
print(dataset[1][column_names[4]][2])
# returns
# 7

# Same as above, but by using the column name
print(dataset[1]['GRID'][2])
# returns
# 7
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick clarification is in order regarding the format of the data in the HDF5 file created by MSC Nastran. The values are not Python Lists, but an NumPy Array. I know, it's deceptive, as both datatypes use [val1, val2, val3], and both uses indexes to access individual elements. ***However, they are not the same.***  You can confirm this by checking the datatype for each field using the `.dtype` attribute as shown below.

Each array has values at multiple element locations. This occurs when your Nastran stress request has (BOTH); you get output at the Centroid and the corners/grids. The locations matches the Grid IDs in the GRID field.

Here is a simple example working with Quad4 element data. The process is similar for other element types:

```
In [1]: import h5py
In [2]: h5f = h5py.File('tube_a_mesh.h5', 'r')
In [3]: str_ds = h5f['/NASTRAN/RESULT/ELEMENTAL/STRESS/QUAD_CN']
In [4]: print (str_ds.dtype)
{'names' ['EID','TERM','GRID','FD1','X1','Y1','TXY1','FD2','X2','Y2','TXY2','DOMAIN_ID'], 
'formats':['<i8','S4',('<i8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,)),'<i8'], 'offsets':[0,8,16,56,96,136,176,216,256,296,336,376], 
'itemsize':384}
```

The `dytpe` shows `GRID` is `('<i8', (5,))` and `X1` is `('<f8', (5,))` (and the same dtype for the other stress values: `Y1`, `TXY1`, etc).
Continuing, this is how to extract the Sx stresses at Z1 location ***as a HDF5 dataset object***.

```
In [5]: quad_sx_arr= str_ds['X1']
In [6]: print (quad_sx_arr.dtype, quad_sx_arr.dtype)
float64  (4428, 5)
```

Alternately, this is how to extract all of the Sx stresses at Z1 ***as a NumPy array***.

```
In [7]: quad_sx_arr= str_ds['X1'][:]
In [8]: print (quad_sx_arr.dtype, quad_sx_arr.dtype)
float64  (4428, 5)
```

Finally, if you only want the centroid values (first element of each X1 array), this is ***how to extract them as a NumPy array***.

```
In [9]: quad_csx_arr = quad_sx_arr[:,0]
In [10]: print (quad_csx_arr.dtype, quad_csx_arr.shape)
float64 (4428,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a better explanation than has already been given as to why the code you have does not work, but I have developed a workaround for my own uses. From what I understand, the way MSC has chosen to format their "corner" results is what is causing the issue. It would be nice if they either come out with a "how to" for reading corner data to a dataframe, or consider reformatting how their data is organized to play nicer with the standard pandas read_hdf function instead of leaving it to the end user to determine how to organize the data.

Replace "h5_file_path" and "table_path" with the necessary information for your specific file/table.

```
with h5py.File(h5_file_path, mode='r') as hdf5:
    header = hdf5[table_path][:].dtype.names
    data = [[item[np.where(row['GRID'] == grid)][0] if isinstance(item, np.ndarray) else item for item in row]
        for row in hdf5[table_path][:]
        for grid in row['GRID']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=header)
```